# How to launch AndroidMarket for rating my application

Tags: android, google-play

I'm trying to force the user to qualify my application. For do that I need launch the AndroidMarket for the user can access to rating web.

Can anyone tell me what is the best way?

I try this, but don't work:

```
String urlString = "market.android.com/details?id=com.pakagename";              
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setData(Uri.parse(urlString));
startActivity(intent);
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this Url:

```
String urlString = "market://details?id=com.pakagename";
```